# SQL Server Bulk import data from .csv into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I can't seem to find the answer to this quite trivial question.

I would like to bulk import data from a `.csv` file (with an unknown number of columns, comma separated) file to a new SQL Server table, within an existing database. The `BULK INSERT` statement works fine if the table is predefined, but since I don't know the number of columns of the `.csv` file upfront, this won't work.

I was trying to use bulk in combination with openrowset, but can't get it working.

By the way: SSIS won't be an option in this case, since I would like to incorporate the query within R (sqlquery) or Python.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear. You want to receive files (.csv) of various widths and lengths, and you want to programmatically import them into a new table, one per file, into your MS-SQL database. Is that a correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: Yes. Ideally I write a query which I can always use to import .csv into a new table. First row of the .csv file contains the column names.

Comment: That seems like an accident waiting to happen. What's wrong with using _SQL Server Import and Export Wizard_ (on a per-file basis)?

Comment: I have to perform this action daily for multiple .csv files and want to schedule it. The .csv files are named conveniently and can be used as the name of the new table. I understand your comment, but think that in this case, importing data programmatically will help me a lot.

Comment: Importing data when the file format is fluid is exceptionally difficult. If I had to do it -- and believe me I'd only do it after a lot of swearing at whomever decided to use fluid data formats -- I'd use something like PowerShell or Python to read and parse the file, use heuristics to determine the file format, and then create the destination table before inserting the data.  My destination format would very likely be a table all fields as VARCHAR fields, and possibly no primary keys at all.

Comment: Simply put, the very idea of an SQL database is that your data is structured in a fixed format.  It might even be best to parse each line and insert it into an Entity-Attribute-Value table, which you can then write a dynamic pivot stored procedure for.  Even then, it's going to really suck to work with.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to ease the pain of manual imports, but what you're saying makes me think that you could define a set number of import schema to be applied to all the various files. I would just want to warn against trying to essentially automate the SQL import wizard as removing its operator from the process is likely to lead to undesired results. You could save the wizards settings per file-schema and reuse them against a new iteration of the same file (eg. customers_feb.csv would have the same file schema as customers_march.csv)

Comment: Thanks @BaconBits for your reply. Maybe I described my question wrongly. What I'd really like to achieve is programmatically import data into a new table, with the column names in the first row of a .csv file. Width is unknown, all columns can be stored as varchar. The idea is quite similar to the import wizard, where a new table is created based on the first N rows.

Comment: Thanks @MaxSorin. You might be right. What I do have working though is a simple SELECT INTO script, which stores the first row into a single entry. The next step would be to create a new table, using this entry for naming the columns and determine the number of columns. That was what I was trying to achieve, build failed to build...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, using R, to solve the problem above. The same logic can be applied in other languages. I advise everyone using this function to keep in mind the useful comments above.

I wrote a small function to capture the steps in R:

```
SQLSave <- function(dbhandle, data, tablename) { 
  # Export data to temp path, for example within your SQL Server directory.
  write.csv2(data,file = "\\\\pathToSQL\\temp.csv",row.names=FALSE,na="")

  # Write first 100 rows to SQL Server, to incorporate the data structure.
  sqlSave(dbhandle, head(data,100), tablename = tablename, rownames = FALSE, safer = FALSE)

  # SQL Query to remove data in the table, structure remains:
  sqlQuery(dbhandle,paste("DELETE FROM [",tablename,"]",sep=""));

  # SQL Query to bulk insert all data from temp .csv to SQL Server
  sqlQuery(dbhandle,paste("BULK INSERT [",tablename,"]
           FROM '\\\\pathToSQL\\temp.csv'
           WITH
           (
             FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
             ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n',
             FIRSTROW = 2,
             KEEPNULLS
           )",sep=""));

  # Delete temp file from file directory
  file.remove("\\\\pathToSQL\\temp.csv")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently struggling with the same problem. I have first read the first row (headers) using bulk insert and created the table. Then again using bulk insert from row 2 imported data in the table. Although you have to change datatype after checking the data imported.

```
CREATE TABLE #Header(HeadString nvarchar(max))

declare @TableName nvarchar(100)='byom.DenormReportingData_100_100'
DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max)=''
declare @Query nvarchar(max)=''
DECLARE @QUERY2 NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
bulk insert #Header
from 'F:/Data/BDL_BI_Test.csv'
with(firstrow=1,lastrow=1)

select @Columns=(select quotename(value)+' VARCHAR(500)'+',' from #Header cross apply string_split(HeadString,',') for xml path(''))
if isnull(@Columns,'')<>''
begin
set @Columns = left(@Columns,len(@Columns)-1)

select @Query=@Query+'CREATE TABLE '+@TableName+' ('+@Columns+')'
exec(@QUERY)
end

select @QUERY2 =@QUERY2+'bulk insert '+@TableName+' from ''F:/Data/BDL_BI_Test.csv'' 
with(firstrow=2,FORMAT=''csv'',FIELDTERMINATOR='','',ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'')'
exec(@QUERY2)
```